# Is there a URL change listener for JCEF

Tags: java, chromium-embedded

Is there a change listener for Java-Chromium-Embedded-Framework that the CefBrowser fires whenever the URL changes? I can't seemed to find this online.

Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/chromiumembedded/java-cef/blob/13ae2d6074bc00a31888fb752dd45f9cf254725d/java/tests/junittests/DisplayHandlerTest.java#L61 There's a mirror of jcef at https://github.com/chromiumembedded/java-cef which is much easier to search the source code through a browser than the bitbucket site

Answer (score 2):

Use `CefClient.addDisplayHandler` and implement `onAddressChange`.